# Create a nested list of ranges based on a list of integers

Tags: python, list

I have a list like `[3,9,14]` and I'm trying to create a nested list using values of `[3,9,14]` as the beginning of each nested list, `increment 1 each step` until it reaches the `next end point - 1`, such that the final nested list will look like `[[0,1,2],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13]]`. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> nums = [3,9,14]
>>> [list(range(x,y)) for x, y in  zip([0] + nums, nums)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> nums = [3,9,14]
>>> [list(g) for g in map(range, [0] + nums, nums)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[3,9,14]
data=[]
x=0
for i in l:
    data.append(list(range(x,i)))
    x=i
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
inputdata  = [3,9,14]
outputdata = []
a =[]
b =[]
for i,value in enumerate(inputdata):
    if i == 0:
        a.append(value)
    else:
        a.append(value-inputdata[i-1])
for i,value in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0:
        data = [x for x in range(value)]
        b.append(data)
    else:
        data = [x for x in range(value,inputdata[i])]
        b.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [3, 9, 14]
result = []
sub_list = []
counter = 0

for i in L:
    sub_list = []
    for j in range(counter, i):
        sub_list.append(counter)
        counter += 1
    counter = i
    result.append(sub_list)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
list_a=[3,9,14]
list_a.insert(0,0)
for i in range(0,len(list_a),1):
    chunk=list_a[i:i+2]
    if len(chunk)==2:
        print(list(range(chunk[0],chunk[1])))
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Haha your username made me laugh